# IPtables - opening ports not working

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, redhat

I am writing a script to open ports based on a textfile, and am having problems opening these ports. For instance, I have tried opening port 18819 by entering the command

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 18819 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d [myIP] --dport 18819 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If i enter : iptables --list --numeric
Result:

```
... 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:18819 
...
```

If i enter: vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
109 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 18819 -j ACCEPT-
110 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7667 -j ACCEPT-
111 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT-
112 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT-
113 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT-
114 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT-
115 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT-
116 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10781 -j ACCEPT-
117 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 18819 -j ACCEPT-
118 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7667 -j ACCEPT-
119 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT-
120 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT-
121 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT-
122 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT-
123 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT-
124 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10781 -j ACCEPT-
125 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 18819 -j ACCEPT-
```

You can see I have entered it numerous times.
No matter what, after I do a "service iptables restart" or save, the ports are still appearing to be closed via telnet (from other machines on same network) and closed via port scanning software. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there really a `-` at the end of each of those lines?

Comment: Sorry- vi shows spaces as a "-"

Comment: (or it could just be my vim.rc)

Comment: You're using -A you probably should use -I.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with your commands.

First of, **DELETE** all your "filter table" rules and start from scratch: `iptables --flush`

Then focus only on what you want and do not copy/paste commands from google without knowing what they do:

You want to open port 18819 for incomming connections, the protocol is tcp and the source can be anything, the interface is probably eth0:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 18819 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, don't lock yourself out of the system:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Finally close all other ports (run as the last command, anything added after this will be useless).

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

If you want to go further then read some docs: start [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/) then [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/iptables-add-rule/) then [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/) and off course, read the man page for iptables: `man iptables`

NOTE: In the first command you were opening the port only for NEW connections, keeping out STABLISHED connections. For the second it shows you are way over your head ;) start simple.

**EDIT:**

You actually need to especify the state of the connection (NEW, ESTABLISHED and RELATED).

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $PORT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport $PORT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Comment: Tried this solution and it does work (kind of) - DROPing all incoming connections makes any connection to port 18819 unnreachable. I tried opening ranges of for loops and keeping the DROP command without success (1-16000).. Any Ideas why closing all incoming ports makes this fail?

Answer (score 0):

okay try iptables -F and then try using 'system-config-firewall-tui' to open the  desired ports and check if it works. In my experience sometimes, iptables behave weirdly and doesn't work using iptables command. I tried to fix it using 'system-config-firewall-tui'. I guess it might be a bug in RHCE 6.4.

Comment: interesting, I am using 6.4 as well

Comment: my flow is now:
flush 
open ports
close remaining ports
save
restart